# Set default props for a react Component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6, redux

I want my app component has a default props , and use that props in  `mapStateToProps`.

### containers/App.js

```
import React, { Component, PropTypes } from 'react';
import { bindActionCreators } from 'redux';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import Footer from '../components/Footer';
import TreeNode from '../containers/TreeNode';
import Home from '../containers/Home';
import * as NodeActions from '../actions/NodeActions'

export default class App extends Component {

  constructor(props, context) {
    super(props, context)
    this.props = {
      info:{
        path:'/'
      }
    }
  }

  componentWillMount() {
    // this will update the nodes on state
    this.props.actions.openNode('/');
  }

  render() {
    const { node , actions} = this.props
    console.log(this.props)

    return (
      <div className="main-app-container">
        <Home />
        <div className="main-app-nav">Simple Redux Boilerplate</div>
        {node.childNodes &&
          <div>{node.childNodes.map(node => <TreeNode key={info.path} info={node} tree={tree} actions={actions} />)}</div>
        }
        {!node.childNodes &&
          <div>no children</div>
        }
        {/*<Footer />*/}
      </div>
    );
  }
}

App.defaultProps = {
    info:{
      path:'/'
    }
};

function mapStateToProps(state, ownProps) {
  console.log('state')
  console.log(state)
  console.log('ownProps')
  console.log(ownProps)
  return {
    node: ownProps.info.path? state.TreeNodeReducer.tree[ownProps.info.path] : {}
  };
}


function mapDispatchToProps(dispatch) {
  return {
    actions: bindActionCreators(NodeActions, dispatch)
  };
}

export default connect(
  mapStateToProps,
  mapDispatchToProps
)(App);
```

### reducers/TreeNodeReducer.js

```
import { OPEN_NODE, CLOSE_NODE, GET_NODES } from '../constants/NodeActionTypes';
import UUID from "node-uuid"

const initialState = {
  open: false,
  info: {} 
}

class NodeModel {
    constructor(path, type, right) {
        this.name = path;
        this.path = path;
        this.type = type;
        this.right = right;
    }
}

let lastId = 0;

function getFileList() {
  var testNodes = []
  for (var i=0; i< 3; i++) {
    testNodes.push(new NodeModel(lastId,'d', i.toString()))
    lastId++;
  }

  return testNodes
}


const getNodes = (state, action) => {
  var { path } = action
  var tree = state.tree ? state.tree : {}
  tree[path] = getFileList(path)
  return {
    ...state,
    tree:tree
  };
};

export default function (state = initialState, action) {
  switch (action.type) {
    case OPEN_NODE:
      return { ...getNodes(state, action), open:true };
    case GET_NODES:
      return getNodes(state, action);
    case CLOSE_NODE:
      return {
        ...state,
        open:false
      };
    default:
      return state;
  }
}
```

---

I have tried :

#### 1: constructor

```
  constructor(props, context) {
    super(props, context)
    this.props = {
      info:{
        path:'/'
      }
    }
  }
```

#### 2: defaultProps:

```
App.defaultProps = {
    info:{
      path:'/'
    }
};
```

but none of them work...
log always is:

[image]

`state` has the correct default value, but `ownProps` is empty...

PS:Project is [here](https://github.com/eromoe/simple-redux-boilerplate) .

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### 1) two "export default"

you're doing two `export default` into `App.js`.

Try changing:

`export default class App extends Component`

to

`const App = class App extends Component`.

And then:

```
...

App.defaultProps = {
    info:{
      path:'/'
    }
};
...
export default connect(
  mapStateToProps,
  mapDispatchToProps
)(App);
```

### 2) "defaultProps" and "ownProps":

As `mapStateToProps` is being called before the component construction (when defaultProps are defined), the `ownProps` is empty. You can try two options:

1) this workaround:

```
App.defaultProps = {
  info: {
    path:'/' 
  }  
}

function mapStateToProps(state, ownProps) {
  console.log('state')
  console.log(state)
  console.log('ownProps')
  console.log(ownProps)

  const path = ownProps.info && ownProps.info.path ? ownProps.info.path : App.defaultProps.info.path;

  return {
    node: path ? state.TreeNodeReducer.tree[path] : {}
  };
}
```

2) apparently, `ownProps` first call is feeded with the inline defined props. So, you can call `<App />` this way in the `index.js`:

```
<App info={{ path:'/' }} />
```

Anyway, after solving this, another error is thrown (`Cannot read property '/' of undefined`) when trying to read `tree` from the reducer (doesn't exist there).

Comment: I tried it, same error. I think the problem is not two `export default` as a lot people write code like that, though I don't know why they write two.. maybe is used to make different `import syntax` compatible .

Comment: you should have only one `export default` per module. But can have multiple `named export` (without the default keyword) .

Comment: But the correct way of setting default props with es6 syntax is setting `MyComponent.defaultProps = { };`. My first thought was that you were importing an unmodified `App` class (that were being default exported) and not the modified with connect method.

Comment: Understand, the repo I fork write the base code like that, I have remove the first default when you tip it. And for current error, any other idea? Would you mind to check my github https://github.com/eromoe/simple-redux-boilerplate ?

Comment: Sorry, I forgot update the code before post the link, updated just now...

Comment: After checking the code, I edited the answer. Apparently ownProps doesnt get defaultProps.

Comment: `mapStateToProps` is being called before the component construction. It is sad to heard that, because I'd like use `componentWillMount` pass `tree ` into props. Anyway, my problem solved , thank you very much !

Comment: You're welcome. Maybe someone else knows a better solution.

Answer (score 15):

I found a better way to set defaultProps,

Because `connect()` returns a new component. If you'd like defaultProps to be present on it, you need to put defaultProps on it:

```
App = connect(
  mapStateToProps,
  mapDispatchToProps
)(App);

App.defaultProps = {
  path:'/'
};

export default App
```

This would work!

Comment: Setting the defaultProps in the container component... great!