# React + Redux props not loading in time

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, redux, flux

I'm trying to toggle a className value based on data received from Redux and passed to my components props. However with this code I am just receiving this error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property '0' of null
```

It looks to me that the props have not been received yet. I have heard about using default/fallback props but was not successful in implementing them.

How might I fix this?

```
calcROI() {
    const myNum = (this.props.value1[0] + this.props.value2[0]);

    let spanClassname = '';

    if(myNum < 0) {
        spanClassname = 'my-class';
    }

    const myNewNum = myNum.toFixed(0);

    return {
        spanClassname,
        value : myNewNum
    }
}

render() {
    const {value3} = this.props;
    const {spanClassname, value} = this.calcROI();

    return (
        <span className={spanClassname}>
            My value is: {value + value3}
        </span>
    );

}
```

Comment: How do you want to fix it? Do you want to use default/fallback value instead?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One solution is to use a default value, in this case is 0 add a few extra conditions when declaring myNum:

```js
// check if this.props.value1 and value2 exists and their lengths > 1
const isMyNumExists = (this.props.value1 && this.props.value1.length > 1) 
    && (this.props.value2 && this.props.value2.length > 1);

// if isMyNumExists is false or props is undefined, set myNum to 0
const myNum = this.props && isMyNumExists ? 
    (this.props.value1[0] + this.props.value2[0]) : 0;
```

**UPDATED**

If however, you want to set default props instead. You can do it by either using propTypes.defaultProps or setting the default props in mapStateToProps. The second case is only valid if you are getting value1 and value2 from the state, which I believe what you are doing. The default value of both examples is [0].

Using defaultProps:

```
// ... the rest of your import
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';


class MyClass extends Component {
  // ... your code here
}

// insert default value here...
MyClass.defaultProps = {
  value1: [0],
  value2: [0]
};
```

Setting default value in mapStateToProps:

```
const mapDispatchToProps = (store) => ({
  value1: store.value1 || [0],
  value2: store.value2 || [0]
})
```

Comment: Thank you, this worked awesome and now I know how to do it. Any idea about this though? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38004703/set-default-props-for-a-react-component Setting default props for the component... Maybe this won't work if i'm receiving the props from Redux? Very curious..

Comment: @fromspace Updated my answer